# Where to save .sql files?

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, xampp

I am creating a .sql file with the following statements that I want to call upon in the mac terminal to create them.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rw_promo_code;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rw_app;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rw_promo_code_redeemed;

CREATE TABLE rw_promo_code (
id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   
rw_app_id tinyint NOT NULL, 
code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
unlock_code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
uses_remaining smallint NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rw_app (
id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   
app_id varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rw_promo_code_redeemed (
id mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   
rw_promo_code_id mediumint NOT NULL,
device_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
redeemed_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I was instructed to save them as a .sql file and run the following command from the terminal;

```
mysql -u username -p promos < create.sql
```

But I am getting a 'No such file or directory' where do I save the following .sql files?

Comment: add the file path to the file name? or be in the same directory when you run the command.

Comment: like this? cd applications ... etc? then run the command? this didn't work either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the path for the file:

```
mysql -u username -p promos < D:\abc\create.sql
```

Note: If your file exist in `abc` folder of `D:` drive.

Comment: @godman,  you need to run like this `mysql -u username -p promos < /Users/useracct/desktop/create.sql`. Here `useracct` means user name of the system.

Comment: I am on mac. Please help me format this line if the .sql file is saved to my desktop?

Comment: the name on my mac is WTL2 so i changed it to     mysql -u username -p promos < /Users/WTL2/desktop/create.sql but still no go..

Comment: maybe my mysql -u 'username' -p promos < ... ('username' should be different?)

Comment: Yes, need to change from `username` to `root`.

Comment: @godman, best would be to go to the folder first through terminal using `cd` and then run the command `mysql -u username -p promos < create.sql`. Try using `cd <foldername>` and go to the folder first where you have your file.

Comment: good idea; i think this might be working but its now asking for a pw and i usually use 'root' for xampp/mamp for a pw and I'm getting an error so i can't tell if its working yet

Comment: Yes it is working and thats why it asked for the password. Need to provide DB password now.

Comment: after i enter (cd desktop) then mysql -u username -p promos < create.sql the terminal asks for a pw which it said it would in the tutorial but when i enter 'show tables;': nothing!